# error:cannot find libary file when trying to link the library file

Tags: c, linker

I have gone through many questions related to linking a library to a c file in stackoverflow, I have followed the approach as follows

**Note:** My library file is in the same location of .c file.

How to resolve these errors ?

1. Using library name with extension

cc consoleDemo.c -L. -lusbcan64.a

-L{path to file containing library} -l${library name}
*The following is the error of compilation*

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lUSBCAN64.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

2. Using Library name without extension

cc consoleDemo.c -L. -lusbcan64

*The following is the error of compilation*

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./libUSBCAN64.a when searching for -lUSBCAN64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./libUSBCAN64.a when searching for -lUSBCAN64
/tmp/ccTh3hGd.o:ConsoleDemo.c:(.text+0x2b9): undefined reference to `_kbhit'
/tmp/ccTh3hGd.o:ConsoleDemo.c:(.text+0x2b9): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_kbhit'
/tmp/ccTh3hGd.o:ConsoleDemo.c:(.text+0x2c6): undefined reference to `_getch'
/tmp/ccTh3hGd.o:ConsoleDemo.c:(.text+0x2c6): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_getch'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b):(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__imp_UcanInitHardware' defined in .idata$5 section in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b):(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__imp_UcanDeinitHardware' defined in .idata$5 section in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b):(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__imp_UcanGetModuleTime' defined in .idata$5 section in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b):(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__imp_UcanInitCanEx2' defined in .idata$5 section in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b):(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__imp_UcanResetCanEx' defined in .idata$5 section in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b):(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__imp_UcanReadCanMsgEx' defined in .idata$5 section in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b):(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__imp_UcanWriteCanMsgEx' defined in .idata$5 section in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b):(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__imp_UcanGetStatusEx' defined in .idata$5 section in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/USBCAN64.lib(USBCAN64.dll.b):(.text+0x2): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: rename your lib to libusbcan32.a, then try cc consoleDemo.c -L. -lusbcan32

Comment: What is the actual name of your `.a` file?

Comment: Your library is for the wrong architecture. Get a 64-bit version (perhaps it should be calleed usbcan64.lib)

Comment: @AdrianGrzywaczewski my question is to how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Pras my library name is libusbcan32.a only, while giving the lib name i gave it as usbcan32, i think that should be fine

Comment: @n.m. I have tried with 64-bit version also, the same issue is there even with that

Comment: So you have a 64 bit version but keep trying to use a 32 bit version with a 64 bit compiler? Why?

Comment: @n.m. Yeah I got what you said, but I just thought of giving a try with 32 bit version that's it.

Comment: If you are building a 64 bit executable, a 32 bit library is irrelevant as it cannot possibly work. Please ask a question about your attempts with a 64 bit lib.

Comment: @n.m. modified the question as per 64-bit version

Answer (score 0):

The first attempt is simply invalid as -l flag and the .a suffix cannot both be specified. Your second attempt exposes three kinds of problems.

1. An incompatible version of libUSBCAN64.a laying around (probably for a wrong OS or CPU). Not a big problem, as you have the right version eventually found, but an annoying warning. Just remove the file.
2. Undefined symbols for kbhit and getch. These are non-standard functions specific to Microsoft products. You need to either link with Microsoft libraries (this may or may not work) or (better) avoid these functions altogether and use standard C instead.
3. Truncated relocations. This could mean that your program is too big or that you have used an inappropriate compilation flags or inline assembly. Google "relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32" and/or post another question with this specific problem and your full source code and build commands.